# Vuejs : suggestions component in table row

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am trying to use autocomplete component "v-suggestions", from https://www.npmjs.com/package/v-suggestions

Want to use in tab row in a loop, since i want to create multiple select boxes, please see the code

```
<tr
                        v-for="ingredient in ingredients"
                        v-bind:key="ingredient.id"
                      > 
                    <!-- https://www.npmjs.com/package/v-suggestions -->
                    <td>    
                    <suggestions
                        v-model="query.suggestions"
                        :options="options"
                        :onInputChange="onSelectIngredient">
                    </suggestions>
                    </td>
                        <td>
                          <input
                            type="text"
                            class="form-control"
                            id=""
                            v-model="items.quantity"
                          />
                        </td>
                        <td>
```

```
export default {
  data() {
    let ingredients_auto = ['Onion', 'Salt', 'Oil', 'Sugar']
    return {
     items: [
        { id: 0, item_name: "x", quantity: "" },
        { id: 1, item_name: "y", quantity: "" },
        { id: 2, item_name: "y", quantity: "" }
      ],
     query: '',
        ingredients_auto: ingredients_auto,
        ingredients_selected: null,
        options: {}

     };
```

```
methods: {
onSelectIngredient (query) {
        if (query.trim().length === 0) {
          return null
        }
        // return the matching countries as an array
        return this.ingredients_auto.filter((item) => {
          return item.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase())
        })
      }
  }
```

I am getting below error in console , any idea why I am see this issue , I think there are issue with v-model, not sure how to fix this

```
vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1888 TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'suggestions' in Salt
    at Proxy.set (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1076)
    at callback (eval at ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?{"cacheDirectory":"node_modules/.cache/vue-loader","cacheIdentifier":"d52508de-vue-loader-template"}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/templateLoader.js?!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js?!./src/views/AddDish.vue?vue&type=template&id=646fb311&scoped=true& (app.b02fcecff20360dbbc44.hot-update.js:11), <anonymous>:189:45)
    at invokeWithErrorHandling (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1854)
    at VueComponent.invoker (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:2179)
    at invokeWithErrorHandling (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1854)
    at VueComponent.Vue.$emit (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3888)
    at VueComponent.query (v-suggestions.js?c4f6:1)
    at Watcher.run (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4568)
    at flushSchedulerQueue (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4310)
    at Array.eval (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1980)
```

Comment: Are you sure you post the code correctly ? cannot seem to find `ingredients`

Comment: I didn't added that portion, let me add

```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had couple of mistakes I have rectified go through this

```
<template>
<table>
  <tr
      v-for="ingredient in ingredients"
      v-bind:key="ingredient.id"
    >
    <td>
        <suggestions
            v-model="queries[ingredient.id]"
            :options="options"
            :onInputChange="onSelectIngredient">
        </suggestions>
        <!-- note the queries array, each item in it binds to a unique item in ingredients array -->
    </td>
    <td>
      <input
        type="text"
        class="form-control"
        id=""
        v-model="ingredient.quantity"
      />
    </td>

</tr>

</table>
</template>


<script>
import suggestions from 'v-suggestions'

export default {
name: 'demo',
components: {
  suggestions
},
// using component locally, but if want to use globally use Vue.use(suggestions)
data() {
    let ingredients_auto = ['Onion', 'Salt', 'Oil', 'Sugar']
    let q = [];
    for(var i=0; i<ingredients_auto.length; i++) {
      q.push('');
    }
    //since we want queries array to be same length as of ingredients/ingredients_auto

    return {
      dish_name: "",
      ingredients: [
        { id: 0, item_name: "Salt", quantity: "" },
        { id: 1, item_name: "Pepper", quantity: "" },
        { id: 2, item_name: "Oil", quantity: "" }
      ],
      error: "",
      selected:[],
      units: ['gms', 'pound', 'kgs', 'ml', 'nos', 'liter'],
      query: '',
      ingredients_auto: ingredients_auto,
      ingredients_selected: null,
      options: {},
      queries: q
     };

  },
  methods: {
      onSelectIngredient (query) {
      if (query.trim().length === 0) {
        return null
      }
      // return the matching countries as an array
      return this.ingredients_auto.filter((item) => {
        return item.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase())
      })
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Note that I have made a dynamic array `q` which I copy to queries because you want each individual textbox to behave independently so typing in one textbox should not affect the text contained in other textboxes

Answer (score 0):

@viney see the

I didn't added that portion, let me add

```
export default {
  data() {
    let ingredients_auto = ['Onion', 'Salt', 'Oil', 'Sugar']
    return {
      dish_name: "",
      ingredients: [
        { id: 0, item_name: "Salt", quantity: "" },
        { id: 1, item_name: "Pepper", quantity: "" },
        { id: 2, item_name: "Oil", quantity: "" }
      ],
      error: "",
      selected:[],
      units: ['gms', 'pound', 'kgs', 'ml', 'nos', 'liter'],
      query: '',
        ingredients_auto: ingredients_auto,
        ingredients_selected: null,
        options: {}

     };
```

Comment: Actually any extra information you want to provide should be added in the question itself not in the answers section, anyway I guess you a new user so that is fine :)